# Static variables memory location

Tags: c

How is a static variable "retained" from one call to another? Does it use something like `malloc` to put it in the program memory, or is there other way that it's stored for all the program to view that variable, for example:

```
static int counter = 4;

[similar to:]
int counter = malloc(sizeof(int));
counter = 4
```

Comment: It’s defined in a segment of memory that has the lifetime of the whole program and can be accessed whenever wherever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static scalar variables (float, int, byte) are stored in the data segment of the memory.
the compiler assigns an address in this memory area that is allocated to the program when it is loaded into memory.
other areas : 
stack (for pushing parameters to function, methods)
heap : dynamic memory used by malloc, new.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment